# Unity 5: No overload for method 'Getcomponent' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Getting a error im new to c# so unsure what's wrong any help is appreciated im trying to make it so that the text on my UI matches what the Health integer is. I cant find any details on this error so im confused

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class health : MonoBehaviour
{

int health = 100;
void WaterColide(Collision col)

{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "water")
    {
        health = health - 1;

    }
    UnityEngine.UI.Text healthtext;
    healthtext = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>(health);

    }
}
```

Water that im trying to walk on: [Unity inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrEQp.png)

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: This seems like good enough to me. It is minimal and complete in the sense that it is sufficiant to understand the problem. providing more would involve giving the whole unity project, which would be overkill

Comment: Sorry that haven't responded I only can view this when in game dev class

Answer (score 4):

`GetComponent` is a method used to fetch a component. You can set properties on that component:

```
var healthTextComponent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
healthTextComponent.text = health.ToString();
```

You are calling `GetComponent` with an argument, which is an error.

Comment: Just going to try this now thanks for quick responce

Comment: Im not having any errors now but when I go on the water it doesn't take any health off me

Comment: I added a picture of the inspector view as I think its a problem with my naming of that

Comment: You are now asking a different question to the one you originally asked. You need to ensure that `WaterColide` is hooked up to a collision system.